# Incremental load without date or primary key column using azure data factory

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-data-factory

I am having a source lets say SQL DB or an oracle database and I wanted to pull the table data to Azure SQL database. But the problem is I don't have any date column on which data is getting inserting or a primary key column. So is there any other way to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it semi-incremental is to partition the table by a fairly stable column in the source table, then you can use mapping data flow to compare the partitions ( can be done with row counts, aggregations, hashbytes etc ). Each load you store the compare output in the partitions metadata somewhere to be able to compare it again the next time you load. That way you can reload only the partitions that were changed since your last load.

Comment: This or change tracking w/SQL DB